# mysql - Weird behavior with varchar column in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table called course_list on in my mysql DB. The SPECIALITY column is of type varchar.

When I do a simple

```
SELECT * FROM COURSE_LIST WHERE SPECIALITY='IM';
```

There is around 386 rows with IM value in the SPECIALITY column but not all rows are returned. I am running it on godaddy hosted mysql through phpmyadmin.

Not sure what is happening. Please help.

Comment: Try LIKE 'IM'. Does that show all rows?

Comment: Perhaps there may be unwanted spaces in the `SPECIALTY` column. Try doing `WHERE TRIM(SPECIALTY) = 'IM'` and see what that gives you.

Comment: Did you check you don't have the result set capped to 100 or something ?

Comment: @Horen LIKE '%IM%' works, Can you please add that as an answer so I can accept it. Zane trim(speciality)='IM' does not work. MS Stp no results are not capped to a limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For string comparisions you can use `LIKE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

The advantage over `=` is that you can use wildcards as `LIKE "%IM%` which will return all fields containing `IM` (what you were looking for)

More info on the difference between `=` and the `LIKE` operator here: [Difference between LIKE and = in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003381/difference-between-like-and-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin adds by default `LIMIT 0,30` to the end of the query just to limit and paginate the result set up to 30 records at a time

Comment: Luis No results are not capped to a limit.