# MySQL operator LIKE and =

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL 5.6 (running on Windows 7 os) database. Inside this database I have a simple table (Bolle) which has a VARCHAR(255) field called bol_gruppo.

This database is populated via a MFC application that connects to the DBMS via ODBC 32. Now a user inserted a group rows where bol_gruppo seems to be 'prova'. I say "seems" because if I perform a LIKE query:

```
SELECT * FROM bolle WHERE bol_gruppo LIKE 'prova';
```

no rows are returned, while:

```
SELECT * FROM bolle WHERE bol_gruppo = 'prova';
```

gives the correct results.
Querying without filters shows that there are rows with bol_gruppo set to 'prova'.
Where is the problem? How can I see what is really stored into bol_gruppo?

Comment: What does this give you?  SELECT * FROM bolle WHERE bol_gruppo LIKE '%prova%';

Comment: did you do any research on this? why not look at mysql's documentation on the two first?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Yes, I have. Maybe I'm little retard but couldn't get the point.

Comment: @SQLDBA Still no rows.

Comment: well I wouldn't call you a retard and you shouldn't as well. but here is another SO post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003381/difference-between-like-and-in-mysql

Comment: = in SQL does exact matching.

LIKE does wildcard matching, using '%' as the multi-character match symbol and '_' as the single-character match symbol. '\' is the default escape character

Comment: @JohnRuddell Well, still does not answer to my question. I'm reading this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: in your case you want to use the `=` operator because its doing an exact match. and its more secure and faster... but if you had something like `Iliveatprovahome` that you were going to compare/match then you would want to use the LIKE operator with the % wildcard comparison

Comment: Can you dump the table (only relevant rows if possible) and make a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) which reproduces the problem? Make sure to get the correct collations.

Comment: @Vatev Ok, gimme a minute or two.

Comment: @Vatev Sorry mate, can't manage to create db. It says: "Forbidde". Maybe it's not a good Monday, I'll try with = and see how it goes.

Comment: well if stuff is showing up with the = then its in the database :)

Comment: @IssamTP well.. whatever works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be that 'prova' has a trailing white space in your data e.g. 'prova '

If there's white spaces LIKE will return no result, however = will return you result.

bol_gruppo = 'prova '

This will return a result on

```
.... WHERE bol_gruppo = 'prova'
```

"=" will treat 'prova' is the same as 'prova         '

However on

```
.... WHERE bol_gruppo LIKE 'prova'
```

"LIKE" will treat 'prova' is not the same as 'prova       '

It will check for exact String unless wildcard is being used / stated so this will return 0 row

> In particular, trailing spaces are significant, which is not true for CHAR or VARCHAR comparisons performed with the = operator:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: Yes, it was a trailing space problem. Anyway I'm wondering why LIKE '%prova%' gave no result as well...