# MySQL can't query using equal to

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, phpmyadmin

I would like to ask one question regarding phpmyadmin search function.
I tried to search this value in one column using search "=" but it is not return any result.Then, i tried again using search "% Like %" and it is success return the value.Why I can not use "=" to search while the value is existing in the database.

**Search using "% Like %" - success(return result)** 
[image: Success]

```
SELECT * FROM tag WHERE reference LIKE '%8100397262011430%'
```

**Search using "=" - failed (return no result)** 
[image: Failed]

```
SELECT * FROM tag WHERE reference = '8100397262011430'
```

Value exist in column 
[image: Value Exists]

Comment: Might be this link helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003381/difference-between-like-and-in-mysql

Comment: For the sake of debugging, run this query and see what is the length of string returned - `SELECT length(reference) FROM tag WHERE reference LIKE '%8100397262011430%'` If it's greater than 16, it means there is trailing space in your string

Comment: I'm out of ideas now..seems very strange

Comment: anyone got idea? still cant solved this problem.already trim and removed leading/trail space but still cant query.

Answer (score 0):

Check the reference column if the value has space. I noticed that your data type is varchar(20).

Comment: if value contain space then how it show using LIKE?

Comment: thanks for your reply,

before this data type is char(20) still get no return value. The value has no space

Comment: @Sadikhasan I think he meant trailing/leading space

Comment: alright, just checking because I encountered that same case and I found out that it is just a space.

Comment: @jun_mich0327 how to remove the space?

Comment: Try to update your reference by using this script update tag set reference = trim(reference) WHERE reference LIKE '%8100397262011430%'