# What is the difference between = and LIKE

Tags: mysql

I am running a query on a column `postal (type double)`.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `postal` LIKE 'abcdef'; # returns 1 record
```

and the same query using = returns 100+ records.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `postal` = 'abcdef'; # returns 107 record
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Try `LIKE 'a%'`  and `= 'a%'` you will see the difference. Also note that you need a String field. I guess that's why you get these strange results

Comment: see following link http://stackoverflow.com/q/1003381/2460470

Comment: Can you please tell us which version (exact version) of mysql are you using? Please note that `Before MySQL 5.5.3, an implicit conversion always produced a binary string, regardless of the connection character set.`

Comment: What is the value in `postal` for the first quey which matched to 'abcdef'?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `LIKE` on a `DOUBLE` field, you should not do that.

`LIKE` is reserved for pattern matching on strings. Use `=` for numbers, or convert your digit to a string first using `CONVERT` and then apply the logic with `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

`=` compares two values for identity.
`LIKE` is for pattern matching ie.  that is, it matches a string value against a pattern string containing wild-card characters.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like)

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` will check and return similar values where as `=` will check for the exact value.

Comment: I am not using any wildcard (%)

Answer (score 0):

The following things affects the result (not the complete list!)

- Implicit conversation
- MySQL extension to standard SQL's `LIKE` operator

In each cases an implicit conversion occours: MySQL tries to convert the values to a common data type. In the first case case `'abcdef'` will be converted to `double` which results to `0`. This is why you get 107 records when comparing with equals (=).

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `postal` = 'abcdef'; # returns 107 record
```

You should get exactly the same result by running

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `postal` = 0;
```

> In MySQL, LIKE is permitted on numeric expressions. (This is an extension to the standard SQL LIKE.)

This means that `SELECT CASE WHEN 10 LIKE '1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` is allowed and results to 1 (matched)

To be honest, I'm not sure which double value could match with LIKE operator with the pattern 'abcdef'.