# How to use '=' and LIKE operator for the same condition together in sql

Tags: php, mysql, url, sql-like

I am currently working on wild card matching in URL. The argument is given by user in the URL should match with the values in database. If the argument is like PDR-*-BC,this should match all the values.

I replaced the * with % in php code.and added LIKE in SQL query as,

```
"Where tablename.columnname LIKE ."'mysql_real_escape_string($arg,$sql)'"" .
```

If the user give "PDR-NRT-BC" in URL ,the sql query with '=' or LIKE would fetch same match, but when argument has white space, LIKE wont return any value.

But for wild card match "LIKE" will help for related matches.

I have to do both conditions (single arg and wild card) in same sql query.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How would you know it is *exact*? What about using `OR`?

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag, just as it isn't a sql-server specific question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between LIKE and = in MYSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003381/difference-between-like-and-in-mysql)

Comment: it has been asked many times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003381/difference-between-like-and-in-mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: This is not like asking difference between LIKE and = .My question is different.

Answer (score 0):

When there are no wildcards "LIKE" is the same as "=". And in SQL Server I am pretty sure the execution plans are the same.

Comment: No,if the data in database has trailing white space,LIKE wont fetch values.But '=' will do