# How to make MySQL count specific rows

Tags: mysql, database, count, return

I wanted to know how to make MySQL count specific rows where a certain condition is true (All rows where the value for foo = bar) and return this value
as a variable like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE foo LIKE '".bar."'
```

and make this return e.g. 20 because there are 20 rows that contain bar

Comment: This SQL looks correct

Comment: What's wrong with what you suggested, other than perhaps the `LIKE` string, which maybe you meant, `'%.bar.%'`? Did you try it? If you really meant strictly `foo = bar` then it should read `WHERE foo = 'bar'`.

Comment: should be `foo=bar` for an exact match, `LIKE '%bar'` for strings that end with bar, `LIKE 'bar%'` for strings that begins with bar or `LIKE'%bar%'` for strings containing bar

Comment: It seems like this SQL appears in a string literal within a programming language. If so, can you provide the complete statement and tag the question with the programming language?

Comment: Well it is meant to look for values LIKE '".$bar."' because upper and lowercase might vary and then count this amount

Comment: Is this really a question about your particular computer programming language's access to the SQL? You haven't really asked a question. You've only made an assertion and some comments.

Comment: This question is a Read The Manual question and shows no effort to research and self-solve.  This question is so basic that it will not serve SO readers in the future.  Please delete this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL different counts between "where =" and "where like"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263964/mysql-different-counts-between-where-and-where-like)

Comment: It was actually difficult to select a duplicate to flag this question, because there were hundreds of different duplicates that ask&answer this question.  user407022, please research and attempt to self-solve before posting on SO.  Look at how many people wasted their time telling you something you could have easily discovered on your own if you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `"` and `.`. Try below code

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE foo LIKE 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

**All rows where the value for foo = bar**

```
select count(*) from test WHERE foo LIKE 'bar';
```

**All rows where the value for foo start with bar**

```
select count(*) from test WHERE foo LIKE 'bar%';
```

**All rows where the value for foo end with bar**

```
select count(*) from test WHERE foo LIKE '%bar';
```