# difference b/w where column='' and column like '' in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

what is difference between

```
select * from dbo.persons where LastName='lkjh';
select * from dbo.persons where LastName like 'lkjh';
```

both retrieves the same values ,both uses exact values to retrieve dta not any patterns and which one is faster?

Comment: See Execution Plan https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: If you read the duplicate link, the verdict seems to be that `LIKE` _might_ be as fast as `=`, but not in all cases, and not in all databases.  I think in general if your logic can proceed using equality checks, then you should lean towards using that.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003381/difference-between-like-and-in-mysql