# SQL query results doesn't accurate reflect AMIGO2 website search

Tags: python, mysql, bioinformatics

I am utilizing `MySQLdb` module for python to handle my sql requests. I am trying to do all my searches programmatically held in the list `theNames`. But upon debugging I find it that most of my search do not show up as reflected on the GO website. I have tried appending the wildcard character `%` before/after/both before and after/in between each white-spaced term but to no avail. An example of my problem is:

```
def queryGO(theNames):
    # db connect
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="mysql-amigo.ebi.ac.uk", user="go_select", passwd="amigo", db="go_latest", port=4085)
    cur = db.cursor()

    # query calls

    sql = "SELECT * FROM term WHERE (name='queuine tRNA-ribosyltransferase%')"
    # query term name directly
    cur.execute(sql)

    for term in cur.fetchall():
        print(term)

    # query term synonyms
    sql2 = "SELECT * FROM term INNER JOIN term_synonym ON (term.id=term_synonym.term_id)\
     WHERE term_synonym LIKE 'queuine tRNA-ribosyltransferase%'"

    cur.execute(sql2)
    for term2 in cur.fetchall():
        print(term2)

    db.close()
```

returns no results. However on the website: [AMIGO2 search](http://amigo.geneontology.org/amigo/search/ontology?q=queuine%20tRNA-ribosyltransferase) does return some things. Another similar example can be seen with the query: "%o-methyl transferase%" and its respective search: [AMIGO2 search 2](http://amigo.geneontology.org/amigo/search/ontology?q=o-methyl%20transferase).

Comment: You have to use `LIKE` if you want to match a pattern. `=` does exact matching.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003381/difference-between-like-and-in-mysql

Comment: This did it! Thank you! Did not know about the `LIKE` keyword. Thought it was only defined by the `=`s.